# How to create a priority queue of pairs in c++. Which pops the element with min value. The default one pops max

Tags: c++

```
priority_queue < pair < long long int,pair <long long int ,long long int > > > pq;
```

In this line of code, I want to form a `priority_queue` on the basis of the first `long long int`.

The queue pops the min. element.

Comment: `std::priority_queue<std::pair<..., ...>, std::vector<std::pair<..., ...>>, std::greater<std::pair<..., ...>>>`

Answer (score 1):

The [std::priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) template allows you to specify a type that meets the [compare requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare):

```c++
typedef mypair pair<long long int, pair<long long int, long long int> >;
std::priority_queue<mypair,
                    std::vector<mypair>,
                    std::greater<mypair> > pq;
```

If all you need is to reverse the order you can [std::greater](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) rather than the default [std::less](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less). In cases that require a more complex compare function you can implement your own.